# How to add has_one through relation with condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model named PersonProject. This model include next attributes: project_manager, developer, project and developer_vacation. Here is the model code:

```
class PersonProject < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project_manager, -> { left_joins(:roles).where("roles.name = 'PM'") }, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :developer, -> { left_joins(:roles).where("roles.name = 'Developer'") }, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :project
end
```

Part of User model code for vacations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vacations, class_name: 'Events::Vacation', inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When creating PersonProject object and add or change developer, I need to automatically add a developer_vacation that must be the last vacation of a developer (developer_instance.vacations.last).

How can I do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `has_one :wahatever_in_here if conditions`

Comment: @noname can you provide example? pls

Comment: `has_one :vactation, class_name: 'Events::Vacations' unless vaction.last_developer_vaction?` something like that, just answering question (How to add has_one through relation with condition?), not sure if code work, but you should get an idea

Comment: @noname I dont understand with your idea how last vacation of a developer will automatically add to person_project obj when obj created with a developer or obj dev attribute was updated

Comment: I just give you idea how to put condition into your model, now your job is to figured out the right condition. I will not give you the entire script.

Comment: @noname right condition based on your idea will not give the result that I asked as I understand

Comment: Is there a possibility that the developer will not have had any vacations? Or do you not need to factor that into it? And is there also a DeveloperVacation model?

Comment: @Doughtz, yes, developer can have no one vacation, in this case attribute developer_vacation in person_project object must be empty. 
about vacation model - it is `Events::Vacation` model as I mentioned in question post

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a scope https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-one

Something like:

```
has_one :developer_vacation, -> { order(id: :desc) }, through: ..., class_name: ...
```

I'm not sure, I guess activerecord gets the first one of the scope, it's not clear on the documentation.